# OpenGL Instanced Rendering

Tags: performance, c, graphics, opengl

I have a very basic OpenGL instanced rendering setup, which is compiling and running, however it is super slow, and even though I spent days of asking and reading how to fix it, I still have no clue, what causes the problem..

[image: Overlapping small window]

What does *slow* mean? At the moment as you can see, it draws

```
16 000 instances (48 000 vertices) @ 512*512px resolution / 38-43 FPS
```

But if I start scaling the window, up to the actual size of my monitor (2560 * 1440) the FPS drops down to 1. I expect at least half a million vertices rendered at 60FPS, that would be the goal.

The setup is very simple, I use GLFW to create the window, GLEW to setup OpenGL properly. So it looks something like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    // ... init window and context
    void *resources = setup();

    // ... start of event loop
    {
        // ... clear, get buff data, viewport
        draw(resources);
        // ... swap buffs, poll events
    }

    cleanup(resources);
    // ... clean up everything
    return 0;
}
```

Now, the functions from the above pseudo snippet are here, they are in the `instrender.c` file. This is where the actual drawing happening:

```
#include <stdlib.h>             // srand(), rand()
#include <jemalloc/jemalloc.h>  // malloc(), free()

#include <time.h>               // time()
#include <stdio.h>              // fprintf()

#include <GL/glew.h>            // GL*

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
typedef struct resources
{
    GLuint vs_id;
    GLuint fs_id;
    GLuint program_id;

    GLuint coords_pos;
    GLuint offset_pos;
    GLuint colour_pos;

    GLuint colour_buffer_id;
    GLuint offset_buffer_id;

} Resources;


/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
const char *vert_shader = "                                 \
#version 150 core                                           \n\
                                                            \n\
in  vec2 coords;                                            \n\
in  vec2 offset;                                            \n\
in  vec3 colors;                                            \n\
out vec3 color;                                             \n\
                                                            \n\
void main()                                                 \n\
{                                                           \n\
    gl_Position = vec4(coords.x + offset.x,                 \n\
                       coords.y + offset.y, 0.0, 1.0);      \n\
    color = colors;                                         \n\
}                                                           \n";


/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
const char *frag_shader = "                                 \
#version 150 core                                           \n\
                                                            \n\
in  vec3 color;                                             \n\
out vec4 fragment;                                          \n\
                                                            \n\
void main()                                                 \n\
{                                                           \n\
    fragment = vec4(color, 1.0);                            \n\
}                                                           \n";


/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void
load_and_compile_shader(GLuint *shader_id, const char *buffer, GLenum type)
{
    // Get shader_id, pass shader source, compile it
    *shader_id = glCreateShader(type);
    glShaderSource(*shader_id, 1, (const GLchar **)&buffer, NULL);
    glCompileShader(*shader_id);

    // If there was a problem during the compilation
    GLint is_compiled;
    glGetShaderiv(*shader_id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &is_compiled);
    if (!is_compiled)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Shader failed to compile\n");
        // Get debugging information
        GLint info_log_length;
        glGetShaderiv(*shader_id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &info_log_length);
        GLchar *info_log = malloc(info_log_length*sizeof(GLchar));
        glGetShaderInfoLog(*shader_id, info_log_length, NULL, info_log);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", info_log);
        glDeleteShader(*shader_id);
        free(info_log);
        *shader_id = 0;
        return;
    }
}


/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#define IR_OFFSET_COUNT 16000
#define IR_COLOUR_COUNT IR_OFFSET_COUNT * 3
void *
setup(void)
{
    Resources *rsc = malloc(sizeof(Resources));
    if (!rsc)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate space for resources\n");
        return (void *)NULL;
    }
    load_and_compile_shader(&rsc->vs_id, vert_shader, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    load_and_compile_shader(&rsc->fs_id, frag_shader, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    // Create new program and get program ID
    rsc->program_id = glCreateProgram();

    // Attach shaders
    glAttachShader(rsc->program_id, rsc->vs_id);
    glAttachShader(rsc->program_id, rsc->fs_id);

    // Vertex coordinates
    GLfloat vertices[] = {  -.95f, -.95f,
                            -.95f, +.00f,
                            -.70f, -.95f   };

    // Vertex indices
    GLushort indices[] = {0, 1, 2};

    // Instance offsets
    GLfloat offset[IR_OFFSET_COUNT];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i=0; i<IR_OFFSET_COUNT; i++)
        offset[i] = (GLfloat)(rand() % 200) / 100.f;

    // Color values
    GLfloat colors[IR_COLOUR_COUNT];
    for (int i=0; i<IR_COLOUR_COUNT; i++)
        colors[i] =  (GLfloat)rand() / (GLfloat)RAND_MAX;

    // Shader layout position
    int pos_index = 0;

    // Setup VAO
    GLuint vertex_array_id;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_id);
    glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_id);

    // Setup coordinates VBO
    GLuint vertex_buffer_id;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertex_buffer_id);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer_id);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    rsc->coords_pos = pos_index;
    glBindAttribLocation(rsc->program_id, pos_index++, "coords");
    glVertexAttribPointer(rsc->coords_pos,
                          2,
                          GL_FLOAT,
                          GL_FALSE,
                          2*sizeof(GLfloat),
                          (GLvoid *)NULL);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(rsc->coords_pos);

    // Setup offsets VBO
    glGenBuffers(1, &rsc->offset_buffer_id);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, rsc->offset_buffer_id);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(offset), offset, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    rsc->offset_pos = pos_index;
    glBindAttribLocation(rsc->program_id, pos_index++, "offset");
    glVertexAttribPointer(rsc->offset_pos,
                          2,
                          GL_FLOAT,
                          GL_FALSE,
                          2*sizeof(GLfloat),
                          (GLvoid *)NULL);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(rsc->offset_pos);
    glVertexAttribDivisor(rsc->offset_pos, 1);

    // Setup colors VBO
    glGenBuffers(1, &rsc->colour_buffer_id);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, rsc->colour_buffer_id);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(colors), colors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    rsc->colour_pos = pos_index;
    glBindAttribLocation(rsc->program_id, pos_index++, "colors");
    glVertexAttribPointer(rsc->colour_pos,
                          3,
                          GL_FLOAT,
                          GL_FALSE,
                          3*sizeof(GLfloat),
                          (GLvoid *)NULL);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(rsc->colour_pos);
    glVertexAttribDivisor(rsc->colour_pos, 1);

    // Link shader program
    glLinkProgram(rsc->program_id);

    // If there was a problem during the linking
    GLint is_linked;
    glGetProgramiv(rsc->program_id, GL_LINK_STATUS, &is_linked);
    if (!is_linked)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Shader program linking failed.\n");
        // Get debugging informations
        GLint info_log_length;
        glGetProgramiv(rsc->program_id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &info_log_length);
        GLchar *info_log = malloc(info_log_length*sizeof(GLchar));
        glGetProgramInfoLog(rsc->program_id, info_log_length, NULL, info_log);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", info_log);
        // Clean up
        glDetachShader(rsc->program_id, rsc->vs);
        glDetachShader(rsc->program_id, rsc->fs);
        glDeleteProgram(rsc->program_id);
        free(info_log);
        rsc->program_id = 0;
        return;
    }

    // Setup indices VBO
    GLuint index_array_buffer_id;
    glGenBuffers(1, &index_array_buffer_id);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index_array_buffer_id);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Set fragment output
    glBindFragDataLocation(rsc->program_id, 0, "fragment");

    // Set basic GL options
    glClearColor(.46f, .71f, .67f, 1.f);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    // Start using program
    glUseProgram(rsc->program_id);

    return rsc;
}


/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void
draw(void *resources)
{
    Resources *rsc = (Resources *)resources;
    glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES,
/* num of elems to draw */  3,
   /* index value types */  GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,
  /* pointer to indices */  0,
/* num of items to draw */  IR_OFFSET_COUNT);
}


/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void
cleanup(void *resources)
{
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ZERO);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glUseProgram(0);

    Resources *rsc = (Resources *)resources;

    glDeleteShader(rsc->vs_id);
    glDeleteShader(rsc->fs_id);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(rsc->coords_pos);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(rsc->offset_pos);

    glDeleteProgram(rsc->program_id);

    free(rsc);
}
```

Environment:

```
Video Card:
    NVidia GeForce 9600M GT 512MB
OS/Compiler:
    Mac OS X 10.9.3 / Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
```

---

***UPDATE 1:***

Based on a friendly advice, which was about *"over-drawing"*, I created a version, where the triangles only have a very limited overlapping in one direction:

[image: Non-overlapping small window]

Now this produces a constant `48-50FPS`, however when I scale the window up to 2560*1440 this number drops down to `22-26FPS` (which is of course way better than the previous `1FPS` but still not the one I'm looking for):

[image: Non-overlapping full screen]

So I guess, the main problem is not over-drawing/overlapping.

---

***UPDATE 2:***

Here is a time profile I created:

[image: Instrument Profile]

As you can see, 75.7% of the time is spent to call/execute the `glDrawElementsInstanced` function, and its subfunction calls.

---

***UPDATE 3:***

During the tests of the code with @syb0rg, another interesting bug appeared: on every 10-15-20th (basically at absolutely random) running the program produces this, and then crashes:

[image: Noise Animation]

Comment: Don't pass around `void*` unless you have to (e.g. because it can be any kind of pointer). In your case you know what it is so you can use the proper type.

Comment: that's exactly the case, why I pass `void *`s in the first place. Ofc the above example is a bit simplified version of the actual code, but in real life, it has to be a `void *` since the caller does not know what pointer that is.

Comment: I don't know about your performance issue, but there's no reason to use indexed draw calls if your index buffer is {0, 1, 2}. That's just a triangle list.

Comment: @Trillian okay, thanks for your comment -- but as I mentioned earlier, this is a simplified version of what I am doing. In my *real* code I'm not drawing single triangles, but more complex meshes, where the indexing is absolutely necessary. The above code is *modeling* that situation.

Comment: Is there a GitHub repository that holds all of this code?  I also have a Mac with similar stats, so I would be interested in compiling and running this program on my machine.

Comment: @syb0rg here we go: [ZIP](http://cl.ly/352B3Z0u3a0f) and then `make && ./build/main` -- and don't press space, ifdef `OVERLAPPING_OFF`. thank you very much for the effort!

Comment: @PeterVaro Interesting bug in *Update 3*.  I am unable to reproduce it though...

Comment: (now it is working as an animated gif)

Answer (score 10):

#### Disclaimer: This is the first time I have ever really looked into using OpenGL

Keep in mind that my review may contain code that is not fully included in the question (such as the simplified `main()` function).

## Bugs

- I found that when I tried to resize the window, I would always crash the program.

  [image]

  That wasn't very fun, so I set out to fix that first and foremost.  It was rather easy to fix, all I had to do was add a frame buffer sizing callback, and set it to the window with [`glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback()`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/group__window.html#ga3203461a5303bf289f2e05f854b2f7cf).

  The frame buffer callback function:

  ```
  static void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
  {
      glViewport(0, 0, width, height); // reset the viewport
      glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); // modify the projection matrix
      glLoadIdentity();            // load an identity matrix into the projection matrix
      glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, -1.0, 1.0); // create new projection matrix

      /// Important!!! You need to switch back to the model-view matrix
      /// or else your OpenGL calls are modifying the projection matrix!
      glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // return to the model matrix
      glLoadIdentity();           // load an identity matrix into the model-view matrix

      // OpenGL has now compensated for the resized window, and is ready to draw again.
  }
  ```

  The modified `run()` function:

  ```
  void
  run(GLFWwindow *window)
  {
      void *resources = setup();
      glfwSetWindowUserPointer(window, resources);

  #ifdef MEASURE
      glfwSwapInterval(0);
  #endif

      int viewport_width, viewport_height;

      // set for proper resizing of window and viewport
      glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

      while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
      {
          glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

          glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &viewport_width, &viewport_height);
          framebuffer_size_callback(window, viewport_width, viewport_height);

          draw(resources);

          glfwSwapBuffers(window);
          glfwPollEvents();
  #ifdef MEASURE
          printfps();
  #endif
      }

      cleanup(resources);
  }
  ```

  This doesn't fully fix the crashing, occasionally the program will still misbehave; however, at least I am able to scale the window now more consistently.
- When I undefined `OVERLAPPING_OFF` to benchmark the code on my computer, I got some errors of an unknown type name `offset`.  Looking at your code, you defined `offset` only if `OVERLAPPING_OFF` is defined but then try to use it if it isn't defined as well.  The fix was simple enough, I just moved the declaration of `offset` outside of the `#ifdef OVERLAPPING_OFF`.

  ```
      // Instance offsets
      int i;
      GLfloat offset[OFFSET_COUNT];
  #ifdef OVERLAPPING_OFF
      int j, idx=0;
      GLfloat x, y;
      for (i=0; i<DIMi; i++)
      {
          y = (GLfloat)i * STEP;
          for (j=0; j<DIMi; j+=2)
          {
              offset[idx++] = x = (GLfloat)j * STEP;   // x
              offset[idx++] = y;                       // y
          }
      }
  #else
      for (i=0; i<OFFSET_COUNT; i++)
          offset[i] = genc();
  #endif
  ```

## Optimization

- Running my own profiling tests for a longer duration, I came up with the following data.

  [image]

  As we can see, `glDrawElementsInstanced()` now only takes up 2% of the total run time.  The big time hogs are `CGLFlushDrawable` and `_glfwPlatformPollEvents`.
- There are two ways to process pending events. `glfwPollEvents()` processes only those events that have already been received and then returns immediately. This is the best choice when rendering continually, like most games do.

  If instead you only need to update your rendering once you have received new input, `glfwWaitEvents()` is a better choice. It waits until at least one event has been received, putting the thread to sleep in the meantime, and then processes all received events just like `glfwPollEvents()` does. This saves a great deal of CPU cycles and is useful for, for example, many kinds of editing tools.

Comment: thanks, I completely forgot about the frame buffer size callback -- nice catch! The offset was a typo, but thanks for pointing that too!

Comment: @PeterVaro Oops, I accidentally rejected your edit when I made the edit of my own!  If you re-submit it I'll approve.

Comment: okay, np, I updated again

Comment: btw: if `glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback` is called -- so a callback function set -- then calling the `glGetFramebufferSize` is absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: @PeterVaro `glfwGetFramebufferSize` directly retrieves the current size of the framebuffer of a window, and stores it in `viewport_width` and `viewport_height`.  It is still a necessary function call (you can see this when you remove the function call and run the program).

Comment: strangely enough, for me it was working without the setter function, also, it is working now, if only the setter function is called and the getter is not. (I can move, resize -- no crash)

Comment: @PeterVaro Odd, I'm not sure what the explanation for that would be.  For me the window looks very odd if I don't call the getter, and crashes when I try to resize it.  The program looks okay without the setter, but crashes more easily if I try to resize it.

Comment: don't get me wrong, but please don't extend your answer with the full GLFW API, I do know what is the difference between `WaitEvents` and `PollEvents` and if I want to test the FPS, then I should use `PollEvents` -- and if that works as it should be, then I can switch back to `WaitEvents` and only switch back to `PollEvents` on animations and stuff

Comment: @PeterVaro Sounds good.  I didn't know if you had tried that before or not, but I thought it would be more appropriate to use for your specific program.

Comment: it would, when it will be in "idle" mode and not in "animated"

Comment: have you changed anything to get such a different data? because as you can see in my profile, `CGLFlushDrawable` is only 0.4% in my version

Comment: @PeterVaro The duration of the test mainly.  I ran it with `OVERLAPPING_OFF` undefined, and with `glfwPollEvents()` like you have in your code currently.